# Multiple child Form components in parent form angular2

Tags: angular2-forms, typescript1.8

I have 2 forms. One parent form, and one children form. It looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="makeSomething()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="test" />
    <some-form-component></some-form-component>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

For some-form-component I use file like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="text" formControlName="somechildfield" />
</form>
```

My component for parent form looks like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {FormBuilder} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-parent-form',
    templateUrl: 'my-parent.form.html'
})
export class ParentFormComponent implements OnInit {
    private form: any;

    constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.form = this.builder.group({
            'test': [''],
        });
    }
    makeSomething() {
        console.log( this.form.value );
    }
}
```

Implementing ControlValueAccessor in my child-form will make it accessible in parent form, but for such multiple child form components in parent-form component do I need to implement ControlValueAccessor in every child form ? Is this an efficient way to do it ?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution ?